# Redirect with RewriteRule keeping keys redirected to the new url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I got this url:

```
somesite.org/news.php?a=0&b=20
```

What I want - redirect it to

```
somesite.org/specialnews/20
```

If you see - key **a** means the type. So a=0 means specialnews. So I need redirect only those urls, that have a=0 and base url (`news.php`) also  to `/specialnews/`.

What I've tried is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=0&b=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^news\.php\?a\=0&b\=(.*)$ specialnews/$2 [R=301]
```

didn't help ;)
Need directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match query string params in RewriteRule, but you can capture paramters via RewriteCond and use it (with %) in RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=0&b=(.*)
RewriteRule ^news.php /specialnews/%1? [R=301]
```

Comment: Seems this doesn't work properly. I got redirected with this url: `/specialnews/?a=0&b=20`

Comment: it works fine imho. you can check it out on my server: http://185.25.150.81/news.php?a=0&b=100 => http://185.25.150.81/specialnews/100

Comment: I got this string after those `RewriteRule ^specialnews/([^.]+)$ specialnews/index.php?id=$1` and that's why it didn't work. I've just replaced `[R=301]` with `[R=301,L]` and it worked out. But why it didn't work as it was - I don't understand.

Comment: But still - how to properly write a rule to get redirected both: with keys (news.php?...) and plain url (news.php) to `/specialnews/`

Comment: So is there any possibility do this by same rule or should I write another one specially for news.php?

Comment: this rule is fire when RewriteCond is met. So if you want another rewrite when above condtions isn't met you should add new RewriteRule

Comment: Oh I see. So this one fits? `RewriteRule ^news.php$ /specialnews/ [R=301,L]`